# QtWebkit: loadFinished and loadProgress slots are never executed

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtwebkit

Here is a basic PyQt code for Webkit I was trying out.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
from PyQt4.QtNetwork import *

class XPrinter(QObject):

    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)

    def print_page_info(self, ok):
        print ok

    def print_load_started(self):
        print 'started loading'

    def print_load_percent(self, percent):
        print percent


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

web = QWebView()
xprinter = XPrinter()
QObject.connect(web, SIGNAL("loadFinished()"), xprinter.print_page_info)
QObject.connect(web, SIGNAL("loadStarted()"), xprinter.print_load_started)
QObject.connect(web, SIGNAL("loadProgress()"), xprinter.print_load_percent)
web.load(QUrl("http://www.gnu.org"))
web.setWindowState(Qt.WindowMaximized)
web.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am facing the problem that the slots loadFinished and loadProgress are never executed. Please tell me where I am doing it wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the new [style signals](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/new_style_signals_slots.html)

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
from PyQt4.QtNetwork import *

class XPrinter(QObject):

    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)

    def print_page_info(self, ok):
        print ok

    def print_load_started(self):
        print 'started loading'

    def print_load_percent(self, percent):
        print percent


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

web = QWebView()
xprinter = XPrinter()
web.loadFinished.connect(xprinter.print_page_info)
web.loadStarted.connect(xprinter.print_load_started)
web.loadProgress.connect(xprinter.print_load_percent)

web.load(QUrl("http://www.gnu.org"))
web.setWindowState(Qt.WindowMaximized)
web.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**EDIT:**
Also you had the wrong signatures
[QWebview](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwebview.html#loadFinished)

```
QObject.connect(web, SIGNAL("loadFinished(bool)"), xprinter.print_page_info)
QObject.connect(web, SIGNAL("loadStarted()"), xprinter.print_load_started)
QObject.connect(web, SIGNAL("loadProgress(int )"), xprinter.print_load_percent)
```

Comment: Yes its working. However, I am trying to find out why the original code didn't work.

Comment: Thanks your edit did help :) However the new style signals are better to work with.